# Can typescript-eslint naming-convention allow numbers?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I've recently updated my `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` from `5.9.1` to `5.38.1`, and it's led my `eslint .` to begin complaining that purely-numeric object indices aren't allowed in my code. Is there some way to configure my ESLint to enforce a convention but not exclude numbers?

EDIT: the warning seems to only appear when numerical indices are *not* in square brackets, as in the example below. So the in-code fix seems easy enough - just add square brackets to any constants - but it would be good if ESLint reacted consistently!

My `.eslintrc` contains the following:

```json
'@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': ['warn', {
    'selector': 'property',
    'format': ['strictCamelCase']
}],
```

I would like to be able to have an object (say, in a test file) like:

```js
{
    0: true,         // should be accepted; currently raises a warning
    8: false,        // should be accepted; currently raises a warning
    [12]: true,      // accepted
    "foo": "bar",    // accepted
    "foo-bar": "baz" // should cause a warning because not strictCamelCase
}
```

The above numeric indices give the following error:

```
warning  Object Literal Property name `3` must match one of the following formats: strictCamelCase  @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Only `foo-bar` is raising a warning with those settings.

Comment: https://typescript-eslint.io/play#ts=4.8.3&sourceType=module&code=MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeAUAbzTGBtADALoBcMUATgK4CmANDgzgPRMwQAWIlANgCYzxqMAIbBg1AA5RqvANwxglcuWpgo3AJ4xywgJYRqEETADuw8mF1gA5tjwAOEjABmw7gfqMYLNpx79BETFJaTkFJRU1TW09AyNhU3NLGzsAImcQEFTSVPhzVM9mVlFxKRk0jJAAWjzybJhc4QAvVO9WDi4+BWFKA2MzCytrAWpgHr6wEFhocl1gKABhYQBbam4lgzQAX1k0IA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6JgQwFtmBzWsgHsmAN0QtKw9GADakAO4doTSABpw2CFk3ZIyREjL5B0aZGLRBpaETUadUAGYmuHfNLnJ8VIwGFuBv76kAC69tgAvuFhEFERQA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA

Comment: It looks like it's something related to square brackets around the indices - I've updated the example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the expected results using the [`filter`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/#filter) property described in the rule.

```
'@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': ['warn', {
    'selector': 'property',
    'format': ['strictCamelCase'],
    'filter': { 'regex': '\\d+', 'match': false }
}],
```

[**DEMO**](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.8.3&sourceType=module&code=MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeAUAbzTGAGAXDFAE4CuApgDQ420D0dMAhsMOQA5TkAm2MAHIQBmTADYQqteoxZtOPPgG0AjACYAuoRIVqUhs1YcuvHACIhIEKcKn4TYqd059sowrMWQAWjsObdgC9TGH0IAAsQUlFuGGAmUglmGAB3ezAASzAAcxh4cjiE8hgwEFhoYnTgKABhJgBbclFaiTQAXwBuNCA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6JgQwFtmBzWsgHsmAN0QtKw9GADakAO4doTSABpw2CFk3ZIyREjL5B0aZGLRBpaETUadUAGYmuHfNLnJ8VIwGFuBv76kAC66g44jpTw+IimGNoRUNCIvIgAHmYAOlkAJgDUdkk4rvhkABbSjhzw+vY6AL71EE2aIRpNDUA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)

The idea is to exclude property names that consist only of digits from being checked against the camel case format. The pattern `'\\d+'` matches digit-only identifiers as required.

Comment: That makes sense! It feels like quite a clunky solution, but works well :) If anyone has any knowledge of why the inconsistency exists then that'd be helpful too...